# Java XML Signature API and Smart Card

Tags: java, xml, xml-signature

I'm prototyping on how to sign XML documents with the Java XML Signature API and I have it working fine when working with a private key from a local keystore but I'm looking for some assistance in how to reach my ultimate goal:

**How/where to extend the JSR-105 implementation so that I could sign the XML document with a Smart Card reader** (where the private key resides behind a PIN code)**?** The https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/xmldsig/overview.html indicates that it should be possible.

The implementation I'm working with essentially runs a REST interface on the localhost where you POST the job in JSON format in order to sign stuff. I'm looking for a way to hook in the signing step so that the Java API basic implementation does the c14n stuff and digests the references and passes "the right stuff" to my implementation for a REST-roundtrip to the card service and then (if the PIN is correct), signs the data and I extract the result and pass it back in order for the Java API to take over and insert the signature in the correct location in the document.

If anyone has done something like this, I would appreciate pointers instead of my having to create decorators for everything and trying to breakpoint myself through the entire reference implementation.

Thanks in advance,
  Nik

Comment: That's a bit broad a question, but I'd consider implementing my own provider with `Signature` / `SignatureSpi` service for that. But first I would check if just signing it entirely on the REST service would not be an option.

Comment: That would be problematic as it would prompt for the PIN once for every reference.

Comment: If you implement things yourself then you are in control. I don't see how that's applicable.

Comment: Of course but looking at the implementation, there is *a lot* of stuff (even ignoring the parts I don't use) when just overriding the actual signature part -> byte[] would suffice.

Comment: Actually, I found a way for using a custom Signature instance through a service with

domSignContext.setProperty("org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.SignatureProvider", new MyProvider(...

now I just have to hunt down how to handle the situation where the key used for signing is actually selected when the Signature.engineSign is executed